# The ProjectLayout.directoryProperty() method has been deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

After update to gradle **5.2.1**

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

So I run `./gradlew :app:clean --warning-mode all`

I have warnings in console:

> The ProjectLayout.directoryProperty() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the ObjectFactory.directoryProperty() method instead.
>
> The ProjectLayout.fileProperty() method has been deprecated. This is
>   scheduled to be removed in Gradle 6.0. Please use the
>   ObjectFactory.fileProperty() method instead.

Even if its a newly created **empty Android project without libraries**.
Also searching for `ProjectLayout` doesnt give any result.

**P.S** I already know that its warning, not error. But I just need to know whats wrong with gradle again.

Comment: This is probably just an internal API that the `Android Gradle Tool` uses, and they will update when they support `6.0` (they support `5.1` now IIRC)

Answer (score 0):

This is just an internal API that the `Android Gradle Tool` uses, and they will update when they support `6.0` (they support `5.1` now IIRC)

The issue is being tracked here (and is currently assigned to a Google Developer)
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127538936